# Forgot password REST services_token

Tags: 7, services

I have picked up some work on a headless Drupal 7 site, using [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services), and [service_token](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_token).

Where the "normal" service login, as I understand it, uses a cookie to authenticate, Services Token allows authentication by passing a token as the username in a basic auth header.

All appears to work well. But I have been asked to implement "Forgot password", and I am struggling to understand how that flow fits with Services Token.

Any guidance most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8 you can reset it by

```
curl  POST 'http://YOUR_SITE.URL/user/password?_format=json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "mail": "USER_EMAIL"
}'
```

Comment: `{
  "message": "No route found for \"POST /user/password\""
}`

Comment: @YogeshKushwaha , please change "http://YOUR_SITE.URL" with your drupal site URL.

Comment: Could you please explain bit more as I don't find this url in REST UI and that's why no route found error exist. I am replacing the ```YOUR_SITE.URL``` with my site url. Do I need to install any module or it is in Drupal core? I am using Drupal 8.9.10

Answer (score 1):

It's already built into the Services module, just enable its corresponding resource then do a **POST** `?q=[my-endpoint]/user/request_new_password.json` and send along a name, e.g.: `name=john` or an e-mail address: `name=john@example.com`

Comment: Thanks Tyler, I have done that. And I have it working with the normal login flow. But the site makes use of `services_token`, and I can't get it to work with that... Am I missing something?

Comment: I haven't used that module, but perhaps just add the token to the URL query string: `?q=[my-endpoint]/user/request_new_password.json&token=abcdefg&name=john`

Answer (score 0):

The solutions, a custom endpoint that takes the token as a password.

The problem we had was that the standard `services` authentication flow relies on cookies and that is a problem/pain when working with AngularJS (apparently).

Hence the use of `service_token`. An update to the two modules allowed for most of the login and forgot password flow. `service_token` for auth, and `services` for forgot password.

To handle the reset (noting that this was not a production site and this was not the most robust of solutions), we added a custom endpoint that took the `service_token` token as the "current password"

Hope that is of help to others.